# How to display email id of user in image source using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am trying to display email-id of user inside image.But email variable i passes is display null.

email id is displaying without image properly.

I am displaying short code here.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("email")</script>
<img src="http://mountainfallsmedia.go2cloud.org/SL22?adv_sub=email" width="1" height="1" /> 
</script>
```

first line of code display the email id of user but if i pass same email variable inside image source then it returns email variable as it.

Here what i get in firebug:

```
<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("email")</script>
pearlnarang18@gmail.com
<img width="1" height="1" src="http://mountainfallsmedia.go2cloud.org/SL22?adv_sub=&quot;email&quot;">
```

Please let me know what i have to change to display email-id inside image.Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: do you mean you want the text of the email to display over the image? and why do you have the image with a height and width of 1, you wont be able to see it.

Comment: yes just pearlnarang18@gmail.com inside image..i passed this in  adv_sub=email"...

Comment: Well with a width of 1 and a height of 1, the user wont be able to see the image. This more looks like an attempt to get someones email and unknowingly to them subscribe them to some advertisement. Which you wont find help with here.

Comment: ok i will change the height and width...yes this email id comes after click on confirmation link .Is this possible to display email-id like i  want??